# Django Rest Framework's Nested Serializers POST Request ForeignKey Error

Tags: django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a blood analysis lab availability check project, I'm using **DRF**(Django Rest Framework) to build the API.

I'm facing Not Null Constraints problems whenever i try to post data that contains a **OneToOne** relationship(**ForeignKey**).

here are the concerned models in my **models.py** file:

```
class Exam(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True,blank=False)
    abbrv = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True,blank=False,null=False)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=False,null=False)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000,blank=False,null=False)
    available = models.BooleanField(blank=False,null=False,default=True)
    _type = models.CharField(max_length=64,blank=False,null=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.abbrv




class Order(models.Model):
    patient = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True,blank=False,null=False)
    total = models.IntegerField(blank=False,null=False)
    done = models.BooleanField(blank=False,null=False,default=True)
    exams =  models.ForeignKey(Exam, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='ordered_exams')
    ordered_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and here are the concerned serializers in my **serializers.py**file:

```
class ExamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Exam
        fields = '__all__'



class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    exams = ExamSerializer(many=0,read_only=1)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'
```

and here are my concerned views in my **view.py** file:

```
class OrdersView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        order = Order.objects.all()
        serializer = OrderSerializer(order, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self,request):
        serializer = OrderSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and here is my available exams that are returned from a **GET** request:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "fns",
    "abbrv": "fns",
    "price": 500,
    "description": "Formule et Numerisation Sanguine",
    "available": true,
    "_type": "hemo",
    "created_at": "2023-04-26T14:16:13.301701Z"
  }
]
```

and whenever i send a **POST** request with this **JSON** object:

```
{
  "patient":"kimanxo",
  "code":313,
  "total":9500,
  "exams":1
}
```

i get this error :
**django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: api_order.exams_id**.

i tried to set a default value to the **order.exams** field,it worked, but all orders were placed under the same exam(the default value), and i couldn't override that by specifying the **exams** id value on the **JSON** object of each **POST** request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit here are the concerned OrderSerializer in your serializers.pyfile:

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
# exams = ExamSerializer(many=0,read_only=1) just remove this line

```
class Meta:
    model = Order
    fields = '__all__'

# Use this to_representation to show the exam detail
def to_representation(self, instance):
    data = super().to_representation(instance)
    data['exams'] = ExamSerializer(instance.exams).data
    return data
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `OneToOneField` instead of `ForeignKey` for a one-to-one relationship. Also, it's better to name the field `exam` since it's a one-to-one relationship, and to use `exam_order` as the related_name for the reverse relation to access the order from the exam instance [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name).

Regarding the issue at hand, in your serializer, you have set the `exams` field as a read-only field. However, since you have a null constraint in your model, you need to make it writable to avoid this constraint. You can change it to a writable field by either removing the `read_only=0` argument or setting it to False.

Comment: the null constraint error is solved after toggling the read only.prop ... But Still, the expected exam json value is a json object with all the required fields for the exam model, yet , the given value is an integer(the exam id)